# Java Application is Unable to connect to correct schema(Error : 404)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, tomcat, web-applications

While trying to start the tomcats we're getting 404 error message in application logs. When looking at the application logs it shows that application is trying to connect to some other schema instead looking/connecting to it's defined schema. Also, we're unable to start any tomcat now.

Below are the application logs :

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: language in COMPLIANCE.ANALYSIS_WORD_LIST

Could someone please suggest why is it happening.

Comment: "*Missing column: language in COMPLIANCE.ANALYSIS_WORD_LIST*" seems pretty clear to me. Your application is expecting a column in the table `ANALYSIS_WORD_LIST` that isn't there

Comment: Yes, I can understand that but the point here is that this the not the actual schema(COMPLIANCE), Actual schema is ABC_UAT, why is it looking for a column in a table which is in another schema.

Comment: Then you have configured your connection pool incorrectly and it points to the wrong schema (user?). Or Hibernate is just being stupid and looks at schemas it shouldn't (which DBMS are you using?)

Comment: We're using Oracle, we've also verified in the connection file and confirm that schema settings looks fine.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate's schema validation? I think for Oracle you must set `hibernate.default_schema` otherwise it will inspect all tables the JDBC driver returns (which is more than just the user's tables)

Comment: Yes, I checked in applicationcontext file and noticed below settings and it's commented :                                           hibernate.default_schema=MY_SCHEMA 
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.max_fetch_depth=4
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
-->

Comment: Yes, we've confirmed that it looks Oracle issue, We locked the application account and restarted the tomcats to verify if application is trying to make connection to same schema and noticed in the logs it found out that the account is locked, which means it's trying to connect to the same schema but the question arises is why is it trying to make connection from other schema and reporting missing table in another schema. No where in application it's mention to connect to another schema. What is causing it to look for another schema.